# Using python to get extent and split coordinates into list

Tags: python, arcpy, extents

I have the following code:

```
for fc in fcs:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    ext = desc.extent
    ext.split(" ")
    print ext
```

I'm getting error: AttributeError: Point: Get attribute split does not exist

I know my fcs list is okay and the extent property is working correctly. I want each fc in fcs to output a list with the coordinates like this:

[-179.168566355952, 51.2134728616834, 179.748708978836, 71.3896098800921, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ext` is an object and not a list so Split won't work.

What you can do is:

```
list = [ext.XMin, ext.YMin, ext.XMax, ext.YMax]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code to:

```
for fc in fcs:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    ext = desc.extent
    l = str(ext).split(" ")
    print l
```

Note you are treating the extent object like a string then the returned objects in the list will be of string format.

Comment: I was able to do this in a round about way but the problem is that the list is now full of strings.